# Visual Studio hangs when creating Azure App Service

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on Azure deployment. I'm stuck on one of the first steps creating the App Service. It seams that the form tries to find all App Service Plans but can't, so all of Visual Studio hangs. I had to kill it with Task Manager. Any clues on how I can fix this? Do I need to create something at the Azure management console?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue, turned out I hadn't installed Azure SDK, you'd think there would be some kind of error message, but no. Installing the SDK fixed issue

Comment: That worked for me too. Here's a link to the SDK: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/azure-tools/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the solution. I have "the azure SDK" (which one of 10?) and that's not preventing the hang.

Answer (score 8):

I did the steps below to resolve the issue.

1. Login to your Azure account
2. Manually create an app service (use any dummy app service name). The service plan and resource group will be created while you're creating this app service
3. Once you see the dummy app service created on your Azure dashboard (it will take around 1-2 minutes), open your visual studio from your pc, create your web project and check api service

--- This time, the service plan and resource group will be brought in.---

4. Click "Create" to create your "real" web/api project in Azure
5. Now you can remove the dummy service from Azure

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  It started to work after I logged into the Azure Dashboard and manually created an App Services Web App.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue a few days ago and here is how I got it working.

I had yet to create any App Services in the Azure account I had tied to Visual Studio and when I got to the Create App Service window you posted, Visual Studio would freeze.

I logged into the Azure Portal, created an App Service with a different name than the project. Once it was created, I then deleted the newly created App Service.

After doing this had no problem freezing in Visual Studio. The fix appears to be to create at least one App Service in portal before it works in VS.

Comment: Worked well for me. FWIW I created a "web app", then deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

I did two things at once, not sure which one got through the lock up.

1) In Visual Studio, went to File -> Account Settings then under the "All Accounts" section of the Account Settings window I reentered my credentials for the Azure account I had linked the project to. This account had a notification raised saying "We need to refresh the credentials for this account."

2) As others have said, I created a new Web App. I'm not sure this was the problem, however - I had previously created a couple other web apps and these resources were still present in my dashboard.

I have to agree with the above comments, too - the error messages provided for this are really, really poor.

Comment: this solution solved my problem. I didn't get the refresh credentials notification, but I signed in again.

Comment: THIS! There was no apparent problem with my account (I had actually changed my password and re-entered them not too long ago) but removing the account and re-entering my credentials did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Check that there are no characters that it will not accept.  For instance an underscore '_'

Azure built a dummy name for me to use including an underscore which it does not accept.  It was trial and error for me to find this where a simple warning would have saved lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

Login to Azure Portal and create necessary resources. VS screens do not seem to work properly.
I created Api App on azure portal and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, however I have 3 Azure subscriptions, but even after making sure all of'em has at least one App Service it still hangs on this step. No other option than to not check the option to host.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Azure SDK on VS2015 fix the problem in my case